# Uploaded file can't set into the selected state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, file-upload

I am creating a file upload using react. I want to set the state variable to the uploaded file(.docx or .pdf) as soon as the it was uploaded. But when the set state calls, it shows undefined.

```
   const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null)

   <Input type="file" onChange={handleImageUpload} accept={config.type}/>
   
   const handleImageUpload = (event: { target: { files: any[] } }) => {
        const file = event.target.files[0]
        if (file) {
        if (file.size > config?.fileSize) {
          setErrorMessage(config.fileSizeError)
        } else if (file?.name.endsWith(config.type)) {
          setSelectedFile(file)
        } else {
          reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        }
      }
   }
```

As soon as the `setSelectedFile(file)` happens, it shows `selectedFile` is undefined. Is there a specific reason why this is happening ?

Comment: have you tried to ```console.log(file)``` inside the condition to see the file content ?

Comment: i did. it shows the file. `selectedFile` is the thing that shows undefined even after setting the state.

Comment: can you try to change ```setSelectedFile({file: file})``` and see what it get you ?

Comment: also tried it. still gives undefined.

Comment: if you try ```console.log(event.target.files.length)``` what does it give you ?

Comment: it gives  it as 1.

Comment: I'll try to answer this problem below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254920/discussion-between-nimantha-fernando-and-cantdocpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your code works as expected, but it's just your state hasn't get updated when you tried to call it.

From the [react official docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#:%7E:text=The%20set%20function%20only%20updates%20the%20state%20variable%20for%20the%20next%20render.%20If%20you%20read%20the%20state%20variable%20after%20calling%20the%20set%20function%2C%20you%20will%20still%20get%20the%20old%20value%20that%20was%20on%20the%20screen%20before%20your%20call.):

```
the set function only updates the state variable for the next render.
If you read the state variable after calling the set function, you will 
still get the old value that was on the screen before your call.
```

Now, this is my speculation, but you can try to add this code:

```
setSelectedFile(file)

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(selectedFile); 
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because your state hasn't updated when you called or logged it in the console. You can log your state in a `useEffect` hook to see it when it updates. Here's an example;

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("File >> ", selectedFile);
  }, [selectedFile]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change `event` type to be a `Partial` instance of `ChangeEvent`:

```
const handleImageUpload = (event: Partial<ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>>)
```

and also changed `onChange` to accept the change `event` and pass it to `handleImageUpload`

```
<input
        type="file"
        onChange={(event) => handleImageUpload(event)}
        accept={config.type}
      />
```

It works properly and you can view `selectedFile` using a `useEffect` hook.